Calling a Python script inside a virtual environment from PowerShell without changing working directory
I am trying to set up a (1)Powershell script that will activate a Python virtual environment with a (2)Python .exe file to call a (3)Python script that requires an (4)SQL query. I want the paths to be relative.

The following script is supposed to do that :
$pythonScript   = Join-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "..\python") -ChildPath "script_python.py"
$pythonVenv     = Join-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "..\python\venv\Scripts") -ChildPath "python.exe"

$pythonStart    = & $pythonVenv $pythonScript
$pythonStart

When working on my (3)Python script, I can just refer to the SQL query by name without specifying a path, as the working directory is implied to be their python parent.
However, when calling the script from my PowerShell script, the working directory becomes the Scripts directory, parents of the virtual environment python.exe file ; thus, the (4)sql_query.sql is not found when my Python script is executing.
How can I keep the working directory to be python just like when I am developping my Python script?

Consider using Convert-Path to convert relative reference to absolute path of .exe. Then have PowerShell change directory, cd, into python folder before calling script so sibling files can use relative reference:
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot

$pythonVenv   = Convert-Path -LiteralPath "..\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
$pythonScript = "script_python.py"

cd "..\python"
& $pythonVenv $pythonScript


thanks for the reply
an ampersand is missing on this part :
& $pythonVenv $pythonScript
without it,the PowerShell will not execute

Correct. You are passing a string command of executable and not actual command, so line needs to be invoked with call operator, &.
